# I keep getting an error message, because a variable is not set immediately

Tags: php, html

Okay, so I'm working on a school project, and currently working on a "shopping calculator", the text is in Norwegian, but that doesn't matter.

My total sum variable is set after the items the shopper wants has been submited via post. It all works fine.
But in the code I'm supposed to add a text with a coupon code if the client shops for over 800NOK. It works, but I keep getting this error before the submit button is clicked: [Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqXkw.png)

Here is my HTML:

```
     <form  action="" method="get">
   <p>Velg vare 1: </p>
   <select name="vare1">
     <option value="Medlemskap">Medlemskap, 500 kr</option>
     <option value="Ball">Select Utlimate Håndball, 600 kr</option>
     <option value="Klister">Select Profcare Klister, 500 kr</option>
     <option value="Ingen">Ingen vare</option>
   </select>

   <p>Velg vare 2: </p>
   <select name="vare2">
     <option value="Medlemskap">Medlemskap, 500 kr</option>
     <option value="Ball">Select Utlimate Håndball, 600 kr</option>
     <option value="Klister">Select Profcare Klister, 500 kr</option>
     <option value="Ingen">Ingen vare</option>
   </select>

   <p>Velg vare 3: </p>
   <select name="vare3">
     <option value="Medlemskap">Medlemskap, 500 kr</option>
     <option value="Ball">Select Utlimate Håndball, 600 kr</option>
     <option value="Klister">Select Profcare Klister, 500 kr</option>
     <option value="Ingen">Ingen vare</option>
   </select><br><br>
   <input type="submit" name="beregn_prisen" value="Beregn prisen">
  </form>
```

This is my php:

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_GET["beregn_prisen"])) {
      $vare1 = $_GET["vare1"];
      $vare2 = $_GET["vare2"];
      $vare3 = $_GET["vare3"];




    if ($vare1=="Ball") {
  $pris1=600;
}  else if ($vare1=="Medlemskap") {
    $pris1=500;
}  else if ($vare1=="Klister") {
    $pris1=500;
} else {
    $pris1=0;
}

if ($vare2=="Ball") {
  $pris2=600;
}  else if ($vare2=="Medlemskap") {
    $pris2=500;
}  else if ($vare2=="Klister") {
    $pris2=500;
} else {
    $pris2=0;
}

if ($vare3=="Ball") {
  $pris3=600;
}  else if ($vare3=="Medlemskap") {
    $pris3=500;
}  else if ($vare3=="Klister") {
    $pris3=500;
} else {
    $pris3=0;
}


$sum = $pris1 + $pris2 + $pris3;


echo "<strong>$vare1</strong>:  $pris1 kr <br>
     <strong>$vare2</strong>:  $pris2 kr<br>
     <strong>$vare3</strong>:  $pris3 kr";

echo "<br><br>Prisen er <strong>$sum</strong> kroner";
}


if ($sum >= "800") {
echo "<br><br>Du har fått en rabattkode for å handle for over 800kr! <br>Rabattkoden er: <strong>2HJ4G7S</strong>";
}
     ?>
```

It all works fine as I said, but I get that annoying error message when the user has not submitted.

Comment: Which is line number 111? The only two references to `$sum` look okay here... after seeing the answers, I realized the mistake we both made when looking at it!

Comment: if ($sum >= "800") {

That's line 111

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simplified version of your code looks like this:

```
if(isset($_GET["beregn_prisen"])) {
    # Do stuff that defines $sum
}
if ($sum >= "800") {
    echo "<br><br>Du har fått en rabattkode for å handle for over 800kr! <br>Rabattkoden er: <strong>2HJ4G7S</strong>";
}
```

Just move **all** the code that uses `$sum` into the `if` statement that controls where it exists or not.

```
if(isset($_GET["beregn_prisen"])) {
    # Do stuff that defines $sum
    if ($sum >= "800") {
        echo "<br><br>Du har fått en rabattkode for å handle for over 800kr! <br>Rabattkoden er: <strong>2HJ4G7S</strong>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This part:

```
if ($sum >= "800") {
echo "<br><br>Du har fått en rabattkode for å handle for over 800kr! <br>Rabattkoden er: <strong>2HJ4G7S</strong>";
}
```

is out of the condition:

```
if(isset($_GET["beregn_prisen"])) {
```

Therefore, $sum isn't defined.
You should put this part in the condition.

```
  echo "<br><br>Prisen er <strong>$sum</strong> kroner";
//} <-- removed this one.


  if ($sum >= "800") {
    echo "<br><br>Du har fått en rabattkode for å handle for over 800kr! <br>Rabattkoden er: <strong>2HJ4G7S</strong>";
  }

} //Repositioned it over here.
```

**Better practice note #1:**
Use indent, it would make it much easier to find bugs or issues like this one. (And it's visually more nice)

**Better practice note #2:**
Instead of using `if()` and `elseif()` multiple times, consider using a `switch()` statement.

Answer (score -2):

$sum is not defined if not $_GET["beregn_prisen"]

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET["beregn_prisen"])) {
      $vare1 = $_GET["vare1"];
      $vare2 = $_GET["vare2"];
      $vare3 = $_GET["vare3"];




    if ($vare1=="Ball") {
  $pris1=600;
}  else if ($vare1=="Medlemskap") {
    $pris1=500;
}  else if ($vare1=="Klister") {
    $pris1=500;
} else {
    $pris1=0;
}

if ($vare2=="Ball") {
  $pris2=600;
}  else if ($vare2=="Medlemskap") {
    $pris2=500;
}  else if ($vare2=="Klister") {
    $pris2=500;
} else {
    $pris2=0;
}

if ($vare3=="Ball") {
  $pris3=600;
}  else if ($vare3=="Medlemskap") {
    $pris3=500;
}  else if ($vare3=="Klister") {
    $pris3=500;
} else {
    $pris3=0;
}


$sum = $pris1 + $pris2 + $pris3;


echo "<strong>$vare1</strong>:  $pris1 kr <br>
     <strong>$vare2</strong>:  $pris2 kr<br>
     <strong>$vare3</strong>:  $pris3 kr";

echo "<br><br>Prisen er <strong>$sum</strong> kroner";
} else {
  $sum = 0;
}


if ($sum >= "800") {
echo "<br><br>Du har fått en rabattkode for å handle for over 800kr! <br>Rabattkoden er: <strong>2HJ4G7S</strong>";
}
     ?>
```